# SELECT/UPDATE/SELECT using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, transactions, pyodbc

I want to find a row in my table, change its state and return it using `pyodbc`.

Here's my query:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 

BEGIN TRAN 

DECLARE @id INT

SELECT TOP 1 @id = [id] 
FROM t1 WITH (updlock, serializable) 
WHERE [state] = 1

UPDATE t1 
SET state = 2 
WHERE [id] = @id

SELECT @id

COMMIT TRAN
```

Here's my python code:

```
cursor.execute(query)
cursor.commit()
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

However, I get this error

> pyodbc.Error: ('HY010', '[HY010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error (0) (SQLFetch)')

**EDIT:**

If I change my query to the following as suggested in the comments

```
UPDATE TOP (1) t1 SET state = 2 OUTPUT inserted.id WHERE state = 1;
```

and run the following code, it will return an ID but the record in database is not updated (the state remains 1)

```
cursor.execute(query)
cursor.commit()
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

If I drop `commit()`, the record is updated properly in the database, but I get an error when running the `fetchall` function:

```
cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

which is like

> pyodbc.Error: ('HY010', '[HY010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error (0) (SQLFetch)')

Comment: Why don't you just simplify the whole code to `UPDATE TOP (1) t1 SET state = 2 OUTPUT inserted.id WHERE id = @id AND state = 1;`

Comment: Perhaps you should consider what happens (and what SHOULD happen) when there is no row `WHERE [state] = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is in double commit, you are committing both in Python and SQL.

Either remove `cursor.commit()` :

```
cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Or remove `begin connection / commit`  in SQL and try again

Comment: If I drop the `cursor.commit()`, I get no error, but an empty string is returned.

Comment: If I drop TRANS in the query, then I get the error of `pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.` when executing `cursor.fetchall()`